# What does ''It's 'bout as bad as it could be'' mean?

Tags: lyrics

*It's 'bout as bad as it could be* is part of the lyrics of *Up!* by Shania Twain. It is the first phrase of the song and is supposed to be a single sentence in itself. Below is the beginning parts of the song:

> It's 'bout as bad as it could be
>   Seems everybody's buggin' me
>   Like nothing wants to go my way
>   yeah, it just ain't been my day
>   Nothin's comin' easily

Comment: _It's about_ is idiomatic, meaning _it's more or less_. _As bad as it could be_ seems clear, can you elaborate on what part(s) of the sentence you do not understand?

Comment: It means that your mother-in-law is coming to stay for a month.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm afraid I didn't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "things can't get any worse".

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the slang

***"It's the pits"***

for the meaning of which run this search at Google Books

[**"It's the pits" slang**](https://www.google.com/search?q=worsest%20slang&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22it%27s%20the%20pits%22%20slang)

and drill in in some of the slang dictionaries pointed to by the search results.